# missing iphone 3.2 simulator support

Tags: xcode, ios5

I have just allegedly downloaded iOS 3.2 simulator support.:
[image: I have just allegedly downloaded iOS 3.2 simulator support.]

However, I do not see 3.X in my Simulator Hardware->Version menu:

[image: Hardware->Version menu]

Looking in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs, sure enough I only see the 4.3 and 5.0 sdk files.

Any ideas as to why I am not seeing 3.2 simulator support whilst Xcode thinks that I should have this support?
(and/or of course, ideas about how to correct this situation)

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list you're seeing is the *Device Debugging Support* list which means the ability to debug a physical device (iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad) of a certain iOS generation. These are not the iOS versions available to the simulator. There is no official way to add a simulator for 3.x to Xcode 4. You would have to [install on old Xcode version](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html) to get the accompanying simulator.

Comment: in fairness to myself I was confused because the 4.3 simulator package is in that same downloads dialog.